# What is the meaning of "steals the show"?

Tags: idioms

I was doing an exercise and I saw the idiom "steals the show". What does it means?

Comment: [Writing Good ‘Meaning’ Questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10565/142322)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To steal the show means to *get all the attention and praise*, or to *become the center of attention.*

For example,

> Whenever Belle is around, Gaston always tries to steal the show.

This means that Gaston tries to direct all of Belle's attention or praise to himself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like the example that you gave.

Comment: Hello, Jazzachi. Please note the reasons why this question has been put on hold. Furnishing an answer merely encourages other such questions.

Comment: Apologies, @Edwin Ashworth . When I posted my answer, the question was not placed on hold.

Comment: Not my downvote; it's people with thousands of rep-points who get that. But look at the standard of acceptable questions.